# Remove body PSR-7 Slim3 middleware?

Tags: php, slim-3, psr-7

I'm trying to redirect user to a login page when is not authenticated. 
I'm using a middleware in Slim3 to check using Sentinel. 
Works but I need to override the body to not show the content. For example, I could use CURL to access to a route like /users and I can get all the page. Because of that I need to remove/override the body if the user is not authenticated.

```
public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, callable $next)
{

    $route = parse_url($request->getUri(), PHP_URL_PATH);

    if ($route !== '/login' && ! $user = Sentinel::check() )
    {
        $response = $response
            ->withStatus(301)
            ->withHeader("location", '/login')
        ;
    }
    return $next($request, $response);

}
```

Comment: When not authenticated, I wouldn't think that the middleware stack would even let the request proceed to any content generation. I think you could do that here by simply returning `$response->with...` instead of letting it proceed to the `$next` call.

Comment: You are right. Also, the body will be restored if I call next. So I cannot change it and call $next.

Comment: Well, you could capture the return value from `$next`, then override the body, then return as required. That's the expected way of modifying something "on the way out", for example recognizing URLs in the body and replacing them with links. Returning early seems by far the better approach for your need, for a number of reasons; just wanted to be clear that it is absolutely possible to modify the response that the next thing in the middleware queue passes back to you.

Comment: Is `! $user = Sentinel::check()` correct?

Comment: yes that works fine, the library(sentinel) returns false if the user is not authenticated

Comment: replace `$response = $response->...` with `return $response->...` as suggested by odan answer.

Comment: I fixed with Greg comment 2 days ago.

Answer (score 1):

You should not call the $next callback if you only want to redirect the user:

```
public function __invoke(RequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, callable $next)
{
    $route = parse_url($request->getUri(), PHP_URL_PATH);

    if ($route !== '/login' && ! $user = Sentinel::check() )
    {
        return $response
            ->withHeader('Location', '/login')
            ->withStatus(302);
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
}
```

Comment: While this code works, `withRedirect()` method is not part of `ResponseInterface` but `Slim\Http\Response`.